# Get genre of music file

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am trying to get genre of the music file on MFC by using:

```
IPropertyStore* store = NULL;
SHGetPropertyStoreFromParsingName(pwszName, NULL, GPS_DEFAULT, __uuidof(IPropertyStore), (void**)&store);
PROPVARIANT variant;
```

, but when i debug, it show as bellow:

[image]

In this case, how do i get the genre (it is classical) or retrieve to the elements of this vector?

Comment: Try ` _bstr_t(variant)`.

Comment: Do you mean:  music.setGenre(_bstr_t(variant));?

Comment: Sorry, ignore that. I think `variant. pwszVal` is what you want.

Comment: No, as you can see above, i used  music.setGenre(variant.pwszVal) but it is NULL.

Comment: Did you try `variant.pwszVal[0]`?

Comment: Yes, i try this but it can't, thank's you so much, and i have resolved by: PropVariantGetStringElem(variant,0,&genre);

Comment: @Sam: Can you please write that as an answer and accept it so that this question can be marked as answered? Thanks :)